# Select only tags that contain text with XPath in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to select only tags (without children/descendants) that contain text.

This is what I am looking for:

```
//*/descendant::text()[normalize-space()]
```

It doesn't work in Selenium. Is there a way to use this expression in Selenium with `find_elements_by_xpath()`?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it not select anything? Does it select elements, but not what you're intending? Is there an error?

Comment: Selenium throws an exception: InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//*/descendant::text()[normalize-space()]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Answer (score 2):

When you say:

> only tags (without children/descendants)

I'm assuming you mean no child/descendant element nodes. If this is correct, this xpath should (I don't use selenium) work...

```
//*[normalize-space() and not(*)]
```

This will select any element that contains text (other than whitespace) and doesn't contain a child element.

For example, it will not match `p` but it will match `b` in this case:

```
<p>text <b>more text</b></p>
```

Comment: My question is a little bit misleading. I want to select every tag that contains text. But to avoid redundancy not their child/descendants element nodes. For your example: Select p-node text, leave out b-node text. Then select b-node text. The expression in my questions selects all tags with text, and skip empty string tags.

Comment: @salnixon - The expression in your question selects text() nodes; not elements/tags. That's the reason you're getting the error. I'm still not 100% sure what you mean when you say you're trying to avoid redundancy. If you use the expression `//*[text() and not(normalize-space(.)='')]` both `p` and `b` are selected. But if the input was `<p><b>more text</b></p>`, only `b` would be selected. Not sure if that's what you're looking for or not. If not, try updating your question with the explanation from your comment. Hopefully someone will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//*[contains(text()='textToFind')]
```

This will basically look for any tag, containing the specified text.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. As I understand it, the OP wants to find elements with _any_ text in them, just not those that do not contain any non-whitespace text.

Comment: Mathias is right. I want to check each node. Get the text, leave out child/descendants nodes to avoid redundancy, then the same for the next node.

Comment: Should be `//*[contains(text(),'textToFind')]`